# Why does instantiating a JavaFX scene control corrupt the layout

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create a simple data entrty application with javafx and ran into a problem when adding a scene control.  The display loses it's fill colour even BEFORE i've added the control to the scene!  Simply instantiating the control breaks it.

I was running on Oracle java 8 on windows, but I;ve tried OpenJDK 8 on Windows and OpenJDk/OpenJFX 13 on linux and all behave identically.  I stripped out the code to the bear minmium to recreate the problem.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class BasicTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        r.setWidth(200);
        r.setHeight(50);
        r.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        r.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
        r.setStrokeWidth(2);

        Text t = new Text();
        t.setText("Confirm");
        t.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        t.setFont(Font.font("null", 40));

        StackPane sp = new StackPane(r);
        sp.getChildren().add(t);
        sp.setMaxWidth(200);

        t.setTranslateY(-2);

        Label b = new Label("Click me");//Comment this line out after first run

        Scene scene = new Scene(sp, 300, 200);
        scene.setFill(Color.BLUE);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

With the label commented out the scene background is blue so I get a white "Confirm" with white outline.  Just adding the label constructor will make the scene background go grey.

Comment: I can reproduce running java 8 on mac

Comment: @Matt interesting. Well, I cannot really say "reproduced", because OP is talking about *grey* background, but with `Label b = new Label("Click me");` commented out I get [*blue* background](https://imgur.com/a/wzZzcXP). Very interesting.

Comment: Easier to see it change by adding this code and commenting out the new label `t.setOnMouseClicked(event -> new Label());`

Comment: Your question is confusing. What is the expected result? I'm not seeing a problem so far.

Comment: @Cypher Read my above comment his wording is confusing but basically just creating an label that is unattached to anything wipes out his `scene.setFill(Color.BLUE);`

Comment: @Matt Thanks, your comment and edit helped to clarify.

Comment: Might be a bug. That behavior doesn't make any sense. Search for bugs here: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/. File a bug report here: https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/.

Comment: When controls are loaded CSS will be applied to the scene as they use CSS.  Without any controls CSS (for performance in straight rendering of graphics primitives) will only applied to the scene if you specifically apply it.  Default Modena css has a gray background in panes.  If you want to get rid of it you need to apply a custom CSS which sets the default pane background to transparent rather than the default opaque gray color.  I don’t have the exact css that is required to do this at this time.

Comment: @jewelsea so what you're saying is that this the correct behaviour..?

Comment: It is by design as far as I can tell and could enhance performance of apps that don’t use controls as it eliminates the need to process CSS in such apps.  Though not really documented and it is of course confusing.  Workaround of a custom css sheet is likely quite straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for all the comments.  Many apologies if my wording was confusing.  I did add some images to show the difference but they seem to have disappeared.  Anyway my thanks to @Matt for their very succinct description (which I wish I'd have thought of!).  I like the mouse click idea too.

I was probably being very naughty asking this "question" on SO when I firmly believe this is a bug in javafx.  Instantiating an object that goes no where near (yet) the scene graph should have no effect on it in my opinion - CSS or no CSS.  I will raise a bug against javafx.

However I knew the power of SO would help me and it has! 
Thanks to the clue by @jewelsea I simply replaced my scene.setFill() (which was only a test anyway) with CSS and the problem is circumvented.  I can even add the control to the scene now and it works as expected.  From the JavaFX CSS Reference:

"The Scene object has no settable CSS properties, nor does it have any pseudo-classes. However, the root node of the scene is assigned the style class "root" (in addition to style classes already assigned to the node). "

So I set up in my css:

```
.root {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
```

Another way to circumvent this is to simply set the background of the StackPane to BLUE:

```
sp.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUE, null, null)));
```

Comment: Note the behavior you're observing is caused by a static initializer in the `Control` class (see [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/Control.java#L98)). As jewelsea surmises, however, this may not be a bug but rather a feature. This setup allows JavaFX to avoid loading the default `modena.css` stylesheet if the user does not use any controls.

Comment: Searching the bug database I found [JDK-8123493](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8123493), which was resolved as a duplicate of [JDK-8088894](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8088894), where the latter demonstrates the problem by simply instantiating a `Label` and doing nothing with it. So it's possible the developers are already aware of this behavior (there may be a more specific bug report, just couldn't find it). Note that one proposed workaround was to simply call `root.setBackground(null)` (while still setting the scene's fill).

Comment: Related question with quotes of some (old) comments and explanations by developers:[JavaFX 8 tooltip removes transparency of stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356992/javafx-8-tooltip-removes-transparency-of-stage/29357577#29357577)